# How to combine two DataSet Tables into one

Tags: c#, dataset

I am attempting to do as stated above combing two `DataSet.tables` into one table. I was wondering if it were possible to do so. I call my stored procedure and it returns my values I set them to a table. (All illustrated below).

Tried:

Adding both table names in the Mapping section `("Tables", IncomingProductTotals)`.

Adding both as one table in Mapping Section `("Tables", IncomingProductTotals1)` `("Tables", TotalDownTimeResults1)`

Doing lots of research most I can find is on sql joining tables.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("L_GetTimeTotals", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = RadDateTimePicker2.SelectedDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endTime", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30).Value = RadDateTimePicker3.SelectedDate;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

var ds = new DataSet();

ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotals");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsA");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsB");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotals1");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsA1");
ds.Tables.Add("IncomingProductTotalsB1");

da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "IncomingProductTotals");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "IncomingProductTotalsA");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "IncomingProductTotalsB");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table3", "IncomingProductTotals1");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table4", "IncomingProductTotalsA1");
da.TableMappings.Add("Table5", "IncomingProductTotalsB1");

da.Fill(ds);

ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsA");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsB");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsA1");
ds.Tables.Remove("IncomingProductTotalsB1");

ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "TimeTotals.xls", Page.Response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Merge method? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach(var t in ds.Tables.Skip(1))
{
    t.Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

edit:
Skip is Linq. You can use this too:

```
for(int i = 1; i < ds.Tables.Count - 1; i++) 
    ds.Tables[i].Merge(ds.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: Sorry for late response skip?

Comment: Doe snot contain a definition for "skip".

Comment: Skip is an extension method from System.Linq.

Comment: I tried this. I got just the columns but not the cell values of the other table